# Using helm commands inside the rpmspec file

Tags: kubernetes-helm, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I'm trying to run helm scripts inside while installing the rpm file. The helm is installed in that machine. And the same commands works fine while running in the shell. But during rpm installation
I'm getting "helm: command not found" error.

These are the commands in the post section.

```
helm init
helm list 
helm install app_name helm_folder_location
helm uninstall app_name
```

This is the format of the %post section in the rpmspec file.

```
%post
#some pre-functions like image loading
is_kube_installed=$(helm list|grep app_name)
if[ ! -z "is_kube_installed" ];then 
    helm uninstall app_name
fi

helm install app_name helm_folder_location
```

This is the error

```
> /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.jzqB04: line 4: helm: command not found
> /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.jzqB04: line 4: helm: command not found
> /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.jzqB04: line 4: helm: command not found
```

What will be the issue? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Using the full path of helm location solved the issue.

```
%post
#some pre-functions like image loading
is_kube_installed=$(/usr/local/bin/helm list|grep app_name)
if[ ! -z "is_kube_installed" ];then 
    /usr/local/bin/helm uninstall app_name
fi

/usr/local/bin/helm install app_name helm_folder_location
```

Comment: You will also want to add `Requires(post): /usr/local/bin/helm` . This won't work unless `helm` was installed by RPM; since it's in `/usr/local` it probably wasn't.